# insert dictionary in tabfile

Tags: python, dictionary

I need help with my program.
I would like to read my tab file and then add a new column (ab) to that file, which I want to get from a dictionary(hi).

My dictionary is named `hi` and for the column I want the data from `ab`.
The data should stand next to the correct special_name like in the dictionary. Please have a look at my example.

My tab file looks like:

```
Names  names_id  first second  special_name
lili      1         a      b     Tm
Katrin    2         c      d     Tm
Paul      3         e      f     ui
bob       4         g      h     zb
tina      5         i      j     ac
```

It should look like:

```
Names  names_id  first second special_name   ab
lili      1         a      b    Tm           a
Katrin    2         c      d    Tm           a
Paul      3         e      f    ui           f
bob       4         g      h    zb           b
tina      5         i      j    ac           a
```

My script is as follows:

```
 with open("myData.tab","r") as file:
      hi = {'ac':{'ab': 'a', 'po':'pb'},
            'Tm':{'ab': 'a', 'po':'h'},
            'ui':{'ab': 'b', 'po':'h'},
            'zb':{'ab': 'f', 'po':'j'}}
      for line in file:
          line = line.strip()  
          columns = line.split("\t")
          print(line)
              for row in columns:
                  file.append('ab')
```

When I print that, I get the whole data but without the headers and without the dictionary. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I can't see where you print it - are you sure that's the whole [mcve]?

Comment: I only did print(line). With that I tested if it gives me the whole data.

Comment: Please also add an example of your tab file and how it should look like afterwards.

Comment: can you be bit clear about your question.?

Comment: I wrote an example in my question . I hope that helps

Comment: There is much in this code that can be improved. 1) your indentation is incorrect. your for row in columns is not followed by proper indentation. 2) You are trying to append to a file that is read only. This will not work. 3) Even if  the indentation and appending to a read only file would work  you would only add the string ‘ab’ at the very end of the file for every column in the file. You never access the dictionary you created to get the value inside of it.

Comment: Also the special_name column does not match between your current file and your desired file. In the current file Bob has zb in the special_name column and in your desired output bob ui in the special_name column.

Comment: I'm sorry. I improved it a little bit.

Comment: @Fox no need to say sorry If I sound too harsh I apologize it was not my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code provides the output as you want in your question. 
There are however a few things to consider when comparing to your original post.

```
with open('myData.tab.tab','r') as input_file:
    hi = {'ac':{'ab': 'a', 'po':'pb'},
          'Tm':{'ab': 'a', 'po':'h'},
          'ui':{'ab': 'b', 'po':'h'},
          'zb':{'ab': 'f', 'po':'j'}}
    columns=[]
    for line in input_file:
        line = line.strip()
        columns.append(line.split('\t'))
    output_list = [columns[0]+['ab']]
    for row in columns[1:]:
        row.append(hi[row[-1]]['ab'])
        output_list.append(row)


with open('myData.tab2.tab','w') as output_file:
    for row in output_list:
        output_file.write("\t".join(row)+'\n')
```

When comparing to your original post the file is still opened the same. The Dictionary is still created the same I only changed the file object name from `file` to `input_file`.

In this code an empty list called `columns` is created. Afterwards we loop over every line in the file very similar to what your did in your code. The only difference is we append each row to the `columns` list.

After looping over every line in the file we create an `output_list` to which we add the first row (the one with the headers) and add the ‘ab’ string to the headerrow.

Then we loop over every row that is a non header row and the value from the `hi` dictionary corresponding to the special_name to each row. Then we add the row to the `output_list`.
Then we open a different file and write each row from our ouput_list to it. Resulting in this output (the result is tab delimited only poorly spaced here on SO).

```
Names   names_id    first   second  special_name    ab
lili    1   a   b   Tm  a
Katrin  2   c   d   Tm  a
Paul    3   e   f   ui  b
bob 4   g   h   zb  f
tina    5   i   j   ac  a
```

A few things of note: This code will give you a `KeyError` if any of your the values under the special_name column is not present in your `hi` dictionary. For sake of simplicity I choose the most easy to understand implementation. But it is vulnarable to `KeyError`

You do not have to write the output_list to a seperate file, you can change the `myData2.tab` to `myData.tab` however this will completely rewrite the file from scratch. Should anything go wrong you could lose the original file. So my personal preference is to (when possible) write to a new file. This way you never lose the original input.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you make use of Python's `csv` library for doing this as it will make things easier:

```
import csv

hi = {  'ac':{'ab': 'a', 'po':'pb'},
        'Tm':{'ab': 'a', 'po':'h'},
        'ui':{'ab': 'b', 'po':'h'},
        'zb':{'ab': 'f', 'po':'j'}}

with open('myData.tab', 'rb') as f_input, open('myData output.tab', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')

    # Copy over the header to the output file and add the new column
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input) + ['ab'])    

    for row in csv_input:
        row.append(hi[row[4]]['ab'])
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Giving you a tab delimited output file, with your header correctly copied over from your input csv file:

```
Names   names_id    first   second  special_name    ab
lili    1           a       b       Tm              a
Katrin  2           c       d       Tm              a
Paul    3           e       f       ui              b
bob     4           g       h       zb              f
tina    5           i       j       ac              a
```

The `csv` library is able to automatically read each row of your file and convert it correctly into a list. When writing back to a file, all you need to do is to give it a list and it will automatically add the necessary delimiters between each value. This becomes more important when you need to deal with strings that might contain the delimiter itself.